# Is it possible to change the point which as3 considers when setting the x,y position of a textField?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have one textfield and I set it's position to for example x=5, y=5. So I have it like this:

```
1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-x
2       
3
4
5       
6       TEXT
7
8
9
x
```

Is it possible to set the textField in a way that the x y value are applied to the bottom corner of the textField like this

```
1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-x
2       
3
4    TEXT
5  
6
7
8
9
x
```

Hope I explained myself correctly.

Thank you in advance .

David

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to extend TextField and override updateDisplayList() with the appropriate logic to calculate this for you. There is no way to explicitly set the origin on a display object.

Comment: And what if I set: this.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER ?

Answer (score 0):

Other than just setting `textfield.y = y - height`, I don't think so.